# .htaccess apply the regex's group result ONLY if it contains something

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got:

`RewriteRule ^(en|fr|it)?/?account$ /page?account&lang=$1 [L,QSA]`

So if you go to `example.com/fr/account`, it works well -- I got the 2 GET params for `page` and `lang`.

However, if you go to `example.com/account`, I got the GET param for `page`, but I also have en empty GET param for `lang`.

Is there any way I can add the `&lang=$1` rule ONLY if $1 actually contains something?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please be a bit more specific. You have posted this multiple times here on SO.

Comment: Your rule works fine if I go to **/fr/account** I see the page **/?page=account&lang=fr** And if i go to **/account** I am internally forwarded to **/page=account&lang=default|emptyPerm** .

Comment: This is different than my other questions, and very specific here: Is there any way I can add the &lang=$1 rule ONLY if $1 actually contains something? The `lang` param should NOT be set at all if it's empty.

Comment: Well, in that case you can use a specific rule , **RewriteRule ^account/?$ /?page=account [L]** Put this above your existing rules to avoid rule's overriding.